# En una query de sql como comparar dos listas

Tags: java, sql

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación de un proyecto de la universidad que conecta java con sql, esta aplicación va de buscar casas, donde no se como avanzar es porque hay un modo en que puedes buscar los materiales que tenga la casa, y puedes ponerlo en modo exclusivo, que esa casa sea solo de madera y piedra o solo de piedra, o de metal,madera y aluminio por ejemplo.

Vale pues con :idComposicion le paso una lista con los materiales que se selecciona desde la ventana de la aplicación, esta parte de la query es la parte en la que se trabaja la exclusividad y aquí lo que pasa es que si pongo madera,piedra,aluminio , me salen las casas que con que tenga solo un material y a la vez tenga tres materiales me salen también, por ejemplo me buscaría casas con madera,hierro,mármol y necesito que salgan solo madera,piedra,aluminio. Alguna idea?

```
        `AND adc.ID_COMPOSICION IN (:idsComposicion) 
            AND  adc.ID_CASA_DISENO IN (
               SELECT ID_CASA_DISENO 
               FROM VIVIENDAS.CASA_DISENO_COMPOSICION 
               GROUP BY ID_CASA_DISENO 
               HAVING count(ID_CASA_DISENO) = :idsComposicionLongitud )`
```

Lo que me gustaría saber es si la lista de composición de ese articulo es igual al que se me pasa desde la aplicación, hay alguna forma de saber si contienen lo mismo aunque los elementos puedan estar de diferente forma ordenada?

Edit2:

Es digamos, conforme este select que devuelve los pedidos que sean de la provincia Madrid, Barcelona y Sevilla, pues imaginar que en provincia marquemos las provincias por la que pasa el pedido y quiero saber los pedidos que pasan solo por Madrid,Sevilla y Barcelona. No me sirve que pase ni por valencia ni murcia ni ninguna otra provincia.

`SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE Provincia In ('Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Sevilla');`

No se si me explico, necesito ayuda y gracias, creo que es sencillo pero no encuentro la forma.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te he entendido bien, pero creo que lo que quieres hacer es que si yo marco que una casa tiene piedra y madera me aparezcan solo las casas que tienen piedra y madera, no las casas que tienen piedra, las que tienen madera y las que tienen piedra y madera.

Si este es el caso, la única manera que se me ocurre es anidando tantos `Select` como materiales tengan las casas. Siguiendo con el ejemplo de la madera y la piedra.

Suponemos que la madera es un material con un atributo `id_composicion=1` y la piedra `id_composicion=2`.

La query quedaría así:

```
SELECT * FROM adc WHERE ID_COMPOSICION=1 AND ID_CASA IN(SELECT ID_CASA FROM CASA WHERE ID_COMPOSICION=2);
```

Si fuera con un material más, es decir, una casa con madera, piedra y metal, por ejemplo metal con `id_composicion = 3`  sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM adc WHERE ID_COMPOSICION=1 AND ID_CASA IN(SELECT ID_CASA FROM CASA WHERE ID_COMPOSICION=2 AND ID_CASA IN (SELECT ID_CASA FROM CASA WHERE ID_COMPOSICION=3));
```

Y claro que puedes hacer un código que haga la query dinámica, metes los materiales que selecciona el usuario en un `Array` y para que la query se actualice dinámicamente te puede funcionar el siguiente código (como no sé qué estructura de objetos vas a utilizar te lo he simplificado con un `array` de `integer` tendrás que adaptarlo a tus necesidades, pero funciona perfectamente):

```
Integer[] listaMateriales = { 1, 2, 3 };

StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM adc 
WHERE ID_COMPOSICION=" + listaMateriales[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < listaMateriales.length; i++) {
    cadena.append(" AND ID_CASA IN(SELECT ID_CASA FROM CASA WHERE     
ID_COMPOSICION=" + listaMateriales[i]);
}
//Metemos los paréntesis del final de la query
for (int i = 0; i < listaMateriales.length; i++) {
    cadena.append(")");
}
//Metemos el punto y coma del final
cadena.append(";");
String query= cadena.toString();
```

Comment: Vale si, y si no sabes cuantos materiales va a seleccionar el cliente?, hay alguna forma de hacer eso recursivamente? Con un for o while en sql?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para tu consulta